# PowerBi dax: summarize rows that pass a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to calculate total number of shops that have sold a product at least 4 different times.

| BookingDate | ShopId | ArticleId | QtyPieces |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/05/2023 | 704788 | 31452 | 6 |
| 10/05/2023 | 704788 | 30891 | 1 |
| 10/05/2023 | 704788 | 30544 | 10 |

The matrix summarizes by Year, Article and Shop.

Counts (distinct) how many shops have sold the item

| year | article id | shop id | count of shop id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 |  |  | 4 |
|  | 31452 |  | 4 |
|  |  | 704788 | 1 |
|  |  | 705588 | 1 |
|  |  | 904788 | 1 |
|  |  | 104788 | 1 |

I would like to know what shops have sold the item at least 4 times

```
CALCULATE( 
 DISTINCTCOUNT(F_Sales_22May23[ClientId]), 
 FILTER( 
    F_Sales_22May23, 
    COUNT(F_Sales_22May23[QtyPieces])> 4 
 )
)
```

This works for individual shop rows, but the condition fails when it summarizes for items and years.

| year | article id | shop id | count of shop id | shops with 4 sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 |  |  | 4 | 4 |
|  | 31452 |  | 4 | 4 |
|  |  | 704788 | 1 | 1 |
|  |  | 705588 | 1 |  |
|  |  | 904788 | 1 | 1 |
|  |  | 104788 | 1 |  |

How can I rewrite the formula so the condition rolls up to higher context levels?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to remove [Year] from the filter context? <gross simplification>
CALCULATE( [Some Count], REMOVEFILTERS('DimDate'))